# How Can I Use Lists With If/Else In Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, if-statement

```
list= ["hi","hello","how are u"]
question= input("please write something")

if list in question:
 print("1")

if question in list:
 print("2")
```

Hey, i am trying to make something, i want to use lists with if else statement. When user write something example "hello what are u doing" and when if statements see the "hello" program will say something.

Comment: So what happened when you tried the code? How is that different from what you expected to happen? Do you understand why it happened? You need to think more clearly about *exactly what you want the program to do*. You need to be able to explain it, as a step-by-step process.

Comment: i thought much, i m trying to do voice asistant, i m not really knowledge in python. I m trying to catch words in questions from users. I of course tried the code but program want to see same things so when i say "hello what are u doing" it cant see only hello it is looking big.

Comment: This is *much* more complicated than you give it credit for. Please try to follow a tutorial for a while and learn the language, before trying to figure out your own project. It's important not only to understand how things work, but to set your expectations.

Comment: sir, i know python but i am web programmer so i dont use python much and i need to make my project for competition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if list in question:`

the aboive line is comparing the list as whole to the question so:
is ["hi", "hello", "how are u"] equal to question? and you also can't compare a list object to string object

```
list = ["hi", "hello", "how are u"]
question = input("please write something: ")
for each in list:
    if each in question:
        print("Hi!")
        break
```

this should work